# Variable does not exist: MetadataServiceExamples

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata, custom-metadata

I am executing this code and its giving me error. I am wondering where I am going wrong

> Variable does not exist: MetadataServiceExamples

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

    MetadataService.Layout layout =
        (MetadataService.Layout) service.readMetadata('Layout',
            new String[] { 'contact-contact Layout' }).getRecords()[0];

    // Add Layout section, layout, item and field
    if(layout.layoutSections==null)
        layout.layoutSections = new List<MetadataService.LayoutSection>();
    MetadataService.LayoutSection newLayoutSection = new MetadataService.LayoutSection();
    newLayoutSection.style = 'OneColumn';
    MetadataService.LayoutColumn newLayoutColumn = new MetadataService.LayoutColumn();
    MetadataService.LayoutItem newLayoutItem = new MetadataService.LayoutItem();
    newLayoutItem.field = 'email';
    newLayoutColumn.layoutItems = new List<MetadataService.LayoutItem> { newLayoutItem };
    newLayoutSection.layoutColumns = new List<MetadataService.LayoutColumn> { newLayoutColumn };
    layout.layoutSections.add(newLayoutSection);

    // Update the Layout
    MetadataServiceExamples.handleSaveResults(service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { layout })[0]);
```

Comment: Did you actually include [MetadataServiceExamples](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls) in your org?

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes I have saved metadataService class in my org

Comment: Not `MetadataService`...`MetadataServiceExamples`. They are different classes.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes I have added its working now.  Can I remove fields from page layout via metadata ???

Comment: That is a separate question.

Comment: @AdrianLarson actually i posted this question but it was put on hold I have even elaborated the description but its still on hold...can you please give reply there here is the link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140283/remove-field-from-page-layout-using-update-metadata?noredirect=1#comment202249_140283

Comment: I mean...how to actually get it working is one you're going to figure out yourself, I think. Or describe a minimum viable reproduction so anyone could reproduce the issue in their own org. Adding the code you have tried is a good step, but I am not sure it is enough to really reproduce. Anyway, reopening takes some time.

Comment: I have edited my question @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost certainly experiencing this error because you failed to include the `MetadataServiceExamples` [class](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls) in your org.